# How to let user to select a coordinate in an image and take those coordinates as arguments for a method in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

For my image processing project, I want to let the user select a point in a given image and take that coordinates as parameters to define a center point for the rotation of the particular image. In the following code, I have defined a method to rotate an image around a center with respect to given position parameters. Can you help me to understand how to do it by letting the user define the rotation center point?

> In here if row_position == 1/2 and col_position == 1/4 it means
>
> > y = 1/2 * total_number_of_rows_in_image ,
> >        x = 1/4 * total_number_of_columns_in_image

```
def rotateImage(baseImage,degree,rowPosition,colPosition):
    rowsNew,colsNew,channels=baseImage.shape
    centre=[rowPosition,colPosition]#these are fractional values

    rotationMatrix=cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(((colsNew*centre[1]),(rowsNew*centre[0])),degree,1)
    rotatedImg=cv2.warpAffine(baseImage,rotationMatrix,(colsNew,rowsNew))
    return rotatedImg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using mouse callback function:

```
def rotateImage(image, angle, center = None, scale = 1.0):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    if center is None:
        center = (w / 2, h / 2)
    # Perform the rotation
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h))
    return rotated

# stores mouse position in global variables ix(for x coordinate) and iy(for y coordinate) 
# on double click inside the image
def select_point(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK: # captures left button double-click
        ix,iy = x,y

img = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow('image')
# bind select_point function to a window that will capture the mouse click
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', select_point)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
if k == ord('a'):
    # print(k)
    # print(ix, iy)
    rotated_img = rotateImage(img, 45, (ix, iy))
    cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)     
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Just double click inside your image to store the `x` and `y` coordinates into `ix` and `iy` global variables respectively, and then press `a` button to call `rotateImage` function with center value and rotate the image around this center.